# Where is the ask question button in the mobile version of the site?

Tags: support, mobile-web

I can't find the ask question button in the mobile version of the site. The full version is not appropriate for mobile browsing on the other hand. Is it somewhere in the mobile version or what?

Comment: It's right there at the top, next to *Questions*, *Tags*, *Users* and *Badges*, it's labeled *Ask*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's part of the list of 'tabs' at the top:

[image: Top part of the homepage of Stack Overflow on a mobile device, "Ask" circled]

Tap on *Ask* to open the editor for a new question:

[image: Top part of the *Ask a question* page on Stack Overflow on a mobile device]